# Clearing out a c# byte array with sensitive data

Tags: c#, passwords

I have a c# byte[] containing sensitive data. 
What is the best way to clear it?
How do I ensure that something like Array.Clear will not be optimized away?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I cannot think of any circumstance in which a call to `Array.Clear` would ever be optimized away and even if it could it would only be optimized away in instances where your `byte[]` was cleared already.

**Edit:** Something else to consider would be finding out if the framework's [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) implementation would be useful in your situation:

> A `SecureString` object is similar to a
>   `String` object in that it has a text
>   value. However, the value of a
>   SecureString object is automatically
>   encrypted, can be modified until your
>   application marks it as read-only, and
>   can be deleted from computer memory by
>   either your application or the .NET
>   Framework garbage collector

Comment: If no one can possibly read the array after it has been cleared, then can't the compiler optimize by not clearing it?

Comment: As a point of order: when you say _compiler_ are you referring to the C# compiler or the JIT compiler?

Answer (score 4):

Even if Array.Clear is guarenteed to be executed (not optimized away) I think you still may have a problem.  The GC can move objects around in the heap and there is no guarentee that traces of the original byte will linger if it was moved from one location to another before Array.Clear was called.

You may want to check out [SecureString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx), [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx), or [ProtectedMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protectedmemory.aspx).  But, if you want a more manual approach I think you are going to have to at least pin the byte array so that the GC cannot move it around.  I believe the SecureString uses this trick as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about Array.Clear, you could always just Marshal.Copy an empty byte array onto the sensitive data.

For example, like this (assuming 'data' is the byte[] containing the sensitive information):

```
        byte[] clear = new byte[data.Length];
        unsafe
        {
            fixed (byte* ptr = &data[0])
            {
                Marshal.Copy(clear, 0, new IntPtr(ptr), data.Length);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

A trick that works with most C compilers is to do something like sum all the elements of the cleared array, and then do something with that sum, like print it or xor it with your return value. That way the dead code elimination won't eliminate the clearing of the array.

That said, are you sure that you only need to clear this array? Consider all the other places where the value may also have existed: a buffer in a form, string objects being passed around, key equivalent values in intermediate calculations, or paged out to disk. Zeroizing this one array only gets you 1% of the way there. You have to clear the entire key path.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing your own encryption routine, my advice would be: don't. You'll get it wrong (as would I, as would anyone who's not a security **expert**). Use a well-known, tested library.

(If not, never mind!) :)

Comment: At some point you need to be calling the library, and you'll need to know how to handle the secrets that you are passing into, and out of, the library; otherwise you cannot create secure software.

Comment: @JirkaHanika Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

I was under the impression that there were already techniques to show the recent state of RAM. Then there's also the MIT guys that flash froze some RAM, lifted it and took it somewhere else and maintained all of the state.

So, if you were paranoid, you'd randomly write a whole bunch of data over your array a few times.

Comment: They did do that.  However that attack assumes access to the physical system.  Defence in depth...

Comment: The real lesson is that you don't put secrets on your client, as your client can always be compromised.

Comment: @Spence: Yeah, I just think it's crazy they can do that. :)

Comment: @Spence That depends on your trust model. For me it's typically the other way round. I, the user, have control over the client (at least that's the ideal) whereas I have no way to verify if the server is running benign code. So my secrets need to be kept on the client and all communications need to be end-to-end encrypted in a way that ensures that the server cannot intercept them.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no equivalent to [SecureZeroMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366877(VS.85).aspx) in CLR. You should use [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx) to store your data.